# Isolating KI3 from solution

Tags: experimental-chemistry

Is it possible to isolate potassium triiodide from KI solution? Sources claim that this is possible because potassium is a sufficiently large cation and triiodide is a sufficiently large anion, therefore it is capable of forming a stable solid. This is an explanation based on HSAB, where triiodide is the soft base and potassium cation is the soft acid. Has anyone tried to do so?

Comment: You cannot obtain KI3 in solid form. KI3 is nothing but a **solution** of potassium iodide and iodine in distilled water.

Comment: @NilayGhosh By evaporating the water away, the ionic solids will be left in solution right? KI3 being an ionic solid may thus also be obtained in this way. Also, what is your reasoning in saying that it cannot exists in solid form?

Comment: You're assuming it's stable...

Comment: For reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triiodide  Note that "some" have been isolated. No one wants to isolate the thallium salt if they can isolate the potassium salt instead...

Comment: If you evaporate all the water, the solid left will be potassium iodide not potassium triiodide. Potassium iodide renders the iodine to be soluble in water by formation of triiodide ion($\ce{KI3}$). Without the iodine and water, the formation of triiodide is not possible. See- Lugol's iodine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, @NilayGhosh already commented on stability of $\ce{KI3}$ in aqueous solution, also $\ce{K+}$ is not bulky enough. But as long as OP didn't mention explicitly that it must be water we isolate potassium triiodide from, there is a workaround, if one desperately want to get its crystals (in an altered form though).

From isopropanol one relatively easy obtains red diamond-shaped crystals of (18-Crown-6)-potassium tri-iodide ([1](https://www.degruyter.com/view/j/zkri.1996.211.issue-11/zkri.1996.211.11.794/zkri.1996.211.11.794.xml)) as the result of reaction between potassium isopropylxanthate and iodine:

[image]

There are also many other examples in the literature showing how one can man make potassium "bulkier", but I found this particular example the most straightforward.

Of course, there is always a fallback option to crystallize ammonium triiodide $\ce{NH4I3}$ ([2](http://scripts.iucr.org/cgi-bin/paper?S0567740870003357)) as ammonium is probably the closest cation resembling potassium for this case.

(1) Sievert, M.; Krenzel, V.; Bock, H. Zeitschrift für Kristallographie - Crystalline Materials 2010, 211 (11), 794–797. [DOI: 10.1524/zkri.1996.211.11.794](https://www.degruyter.com/view/j/zkri.1996.211.issue-11/zkri.1996.211.11.794/zkri.1996.211.11.794.xml)
(2) Cheesman, G. H.; Finney, A. J. T. Acta Cryst B, 1970, 26 (7), 904–906. [DOI: 10.1107/S0567740870003357](http://scripts.iucr.org/cgi-bin/paper?S0567740870003357)

Comment: Thanks. Although I was really hoping to get pure crystals, I am fine with getting these not so pure ones as well. I just want to know whether it is isolatable or not. Once again, thanks for your insightful response.